# Facebook Ads - update url_tags

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-ads-api

I am using Facebook Ads SDK v2.6.0 and I would like to update the `url_tags` of an Ad.

`$ad->creative['id']` contains the AdCreative's ID and is OK since `read()` returns actual data.

```
$creative = new AdCreative($ad->creative['id']);
$creativeData = $creative->read([
    'link_url', 
    'name', 
    'object_story_spec', 
    'object_story_id', 
    'url_tags'
]); // $creativeData->url_tags is OK and contains tags we have now

$creative->setData(['url_tags' => "a=b&c=d"]);
$creative->update();
```

Then everything seems to work fine, the response is received and the result is `{"success": true}`.

[image: Breakpoint in <code>FacebookAds\Api::executeRequest</code>]

No exceptions are thrown and everything goes smooth, but the url_params is updated neither in Facebook Ads Manager nor the field `$creativeData->url_tags` when I run the script again.

P.S. I was able to update the `object_story_spec` of AdCreative, but I would precisely since it wouldn't cause the ad to be re-approved.

Best regards, Alexander

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `url_tags` are not one of the mutable fields of an `AdCreative` object, so you will have to re-create the creative with the new `url_tags` in order to achieve this.

The following section of the docs outlines which fields are mutable:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative#Updating

Comment: I got your point, but want to know how replace existing Ad Creative with new duplicate one but with new URL tags?